# java, unable to color cells with proper color, apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to color 3 different sets of columns with 3 different colors, and this method is used to add the colors:

```
public static void addCellStyles(CellStyle stylex, CellStyle styley, CellStyle stylez){

    stylex.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_GREEN.getIndex());
    stylex.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    stylex.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
    stylex.setVerticalAlignment(CellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER);

    styley.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_ORANGE.getIndex());
    styley.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    styley.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
    styley.setVerticalAlignment(CellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER);

    stylez.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_CORNFLOWER_BLUE.getIndex());
    stylez.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    stylez.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
    stylez.setVerticalAlignment(CellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER);
}
```

i'm assigning the CellStyles to the respective cells in the main function
for some reason the cells are being colored black, and i cant seem to find any problem
can anyone help me

Answer (score 2):

Ironically the background-color is the foreground-color in POI/Excel.

Try it like this:

```
XSSFCellStyle style1 = workbook.createCellStyle();
style1.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(128, 0, 128)));
style1.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
cell.setCellStyle(style1);
```

or in your case simply:

```
stylex.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_GREEN.getIndex());
stylex.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```

and don't forget to assign the style to the cells. If you just take the initial style from three different cells, it will probably point to the same style object in the workbook. If you want a new style you have to create it in the workbook and assign it to the cell (see my example).